# How to write a command which uses the prefix argument AND some strings

Tags: commands, interactive, prefix-argument, defun

I want to write a command which uses a prefix argument **and** reads some strings.

I know both parts individually:

```
(defun xtest(arg)
  (interactive "P")
  ...
```

reads the prefix arg.

````
(defun xtest(t1 t2)
  (interactive "stEins: \nstZwei: ")
  (message "%s %s %s" arg t1 t2))```
````

reads two strings. But when I put it together to use both:

```
(defun xtest(arg t1 t2)
  (interactive "PstEins: \nstZwei: ")
  ...
```

then I get on execution of the command the error "funcall-interactively: Wrong number of arguments".

How do I set up the function definition correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string example shows that you *already* know how to separate multiple interactive arguments, by putting a newline between each one in the interactive spec.

So rather than:

```
(interactive "PstEins: \nstZwei: ")
```

You wanted:

```
(interactive "P\nstEins: \nstZwei: ")
```

Comment: Cool! I though the newline is just a divider for strings...